# Not able to read string in a structure

Tags: c++, string, struct

When I run the program it straight away goes to the enter marks part and skips the getline part altogether. Also when I use cin it works fine but then I obviously can't read the full name. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the struct with functions to input and output:

```
struct student
 {
    string name;
    float marks;

 void getinfo()
{
    cout<<"Enter name:\n"; getline (cin , name); //This part gets skipped
    cout<<"Enter marks:\n"; cin>>marks; cout<<endl;
}

void showinfo()
{
    cout<<"\nName: "<<name;
    cout<<"\nMarks: \n"<<marks;
}
};
```

And here is the function where I call it:

```
void stack::push()
{
    if(top==4)
        cout<<"Overflow!\n";
    else
    {
        top++;
        S[top].getinfo();
    }
}
```

Lastly, here's the class stack:

```
class stack
{
    student S[5];
    int top;

public:

    stack() { top=-1;}
    void push();
    void pop();
    void display();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mix `cin` and `getline` usage you have to remember that `cin` usually leaves `\n` character in keyboard buffer. When `getline` ckecks buffer it see `\n` character as first and immediately ends. Use `cin.ignore` before `getline` function to remove `\n` character.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. The program runs fine now. Just wanted to know if there is any better way to input a number and string next to each other?

Comment: Well, your method is correct. You only need to remember about mentioned constraints.